# What do you use for linux keyboard macros?

Tags: automation, macros, autohotkey, hotkeys

I've tried IronAHK and xbindkeys. Xbindkeys was ok I guess and ironAHK didn't compile. Just wondering if there's better. Maybe something to where I could set emacs-like bindings when certain programs come into focus. A mix between devilspie and xbindkeys. So long as it can execute shell commands it's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I did a research on that I've stopped on [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/). It's not an ideal though. E.g. you can "send keys" to programs, but not to x-server: you can't send a "Switch keyboard layout" keys for example (of course you can send them - but it gives no effect...). Also I can't record macro (there is a button - but it looks like it's not yet fully developed).

Still here are some scripts I use (you can bind them to a key). This inserts date:

```
 #Enter script code
 output = system.exec_command("date +%b'-'%d'-'%Y")
 keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

And this one inserts previous copied item:

```
 #Enter script code
 output = system.exec_command("qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardHistoryItem 1")
 keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

Also it's not easy to find manual on the official site. And the copy of manual is [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/cf42a8f/n/AutoKey-Manual.tar.bz2).