# Telling any program to perform some action

Tags: linux, automation

In linux (Ubuntu 10.04) is there a command line way to tell a program to preform an action? Let's say, for example, `tell pid 12345 to execute "Ctrl+S"` without stealing focus from my current window?

I don't think what I'm looking for is a "macro" because I want it to be executed in the background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous answer that may help: [Adobe's answer to 'What do you use for linux keyboard macros?'](https://superuser.com/a/328985/109738)

Comment: It's indeed a macro usage, since I cannot send a command to a window without first bringing it to focus.